# SqlBulkCopy vs SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis, sqlbulkcopy

I was trying to write a program to perform large table, around 2 billions records, to another table. It looks to me that SqlBulkCopy will need to wait until all data is read from the SqlDataReader before inserting. If I use the same query and table in SSIS, SSIS was started right away and I could see data inserting from the target table.

Am I coding it correctly? How can I make it SSIS alike?

```cs
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(bukCopyData.SourceQuery, conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            performBulkCopy(connectionStringDest, DestinationTable, reader);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
private void performBulkCopy(string connectionString, string destinationTable, SqlDataReader reader)
{
    using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString,
        SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity | SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls
        ))
    {
        sbc.DestinationTableName = destinationTable;
        sbc.BatchSize = 102400;
        sbc.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
        try
        {
            sbc.WriteToServer(reader);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        } finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have a try/catch block with only a throw statement? Why bother with the try/catch in the first place? And what makes you think that you have to read all the data with SqlBulkCopy before writing it to the destination?

Comment: I checked the database activities using sp_whoisactive. I could only see the select query but not the bulk insert when running the program. However, if I use SSIS, then I could see both select and bulk insert right away

Comment: Have you tried playing with the batch size? I'm by no means a SqlkBulkCopy expert, but just from looking at it I would think that if you do a huge batch size like that, it's going to load all the records for that batch, then try to insert them. Perhaps try a much smaller batch size, or leave it at the default. And again: remove that useless try/catch. Not need to manually close the reader either, since the reader was declared in a using block it will automatically get closed and disposed of when it goes out of scope.

Comment: I think the batch size should be fine. I was referring to an SSIS article but trying to see if I can convert it to a C# program

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/using-ssis-to-load-1tb-data-into-sql-server-in-30-mins-with/ba-p/388322

It was reading from CSV file but I wanted to load from a database table

Comment: Find this but it does not seem to help either

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.enablestreaming?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: What are you basing your "I think batch size should be fine" statement off of? Have you tried it with the default and/or with a smaller batch size?

Comment: Use c# to load that much data is going to be very slow.  Best way of uploading is to use one of the SQL command line utilities like SQLCMD which is meant to upload/archive SQL databases and is very efficient.  The SALCMD is built into the Power Shell and crating a Power Shell Script that will run from c# is one possible way of going.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Hi jdweng, I need to read the data from the database and put it in another database/table. How would the tools like bcp help?

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, the EnableStreaming property seems to work. I had to make sure the column order in the query is matching with the target table. Not sure why it needs a long time to throw the error.